# Nested while loop assignment gives unexpected results in Java

Tags: java, loops

I have a nested assignment inside a while loop which gives me unexpected results.
The code below is running in a thread that writes package data to file. The packages are recieved from another thread through a ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

This code never enters the write section for as long as the producer is putting packages in the queue.

```
Packet packet = null;
while (!done || (packet = queue.poll()) != null){
    if (packet != null){
        packet.write(bufferedOutputStream);
    }
    else{
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

However, this code does enter the write section as soon as there is a packet in the queue. This is for me the expected behaviour.

```
Packet packet = null;
while (!done || packet != null){
    packet = queue.poll();
    if (packet != null){
        packet.write(bufferedOutputStream);
    }
    else{
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing out on? Why are these code snippets producing different results?

Comment: How is this regarded as a duplicate question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while (!done || (packet = queue.poll()) != null){
    ...
```

`||` is short-circuited. That means that if the first operand is true, the second is not evaluated.

For this code, that means that if `done` is false, `(packet = queue.poll()) != null` will not be evaluated, so `packet` will not be reassigned.

Comment: Ah that's right. Sweet, I couldn't see it!